# Highlight cells in MS excel 2007 by double click

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, highlight

I want the user to be able to just highlight one cell on each row

This code highlights the cells in excel 2007, but my problem is that I can't write a code the restrict the user to highlight just one cell on a row,

here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick( _


     ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

' This macro is activated when you doubleclick
' on a cell on a worksheet.
' Purpose: color or decolor the cell when clicked on again
' by default color number 3 is red
      If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            ' if cell is already red, remove the color:
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
      Else
            ' make the cell red:
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End If
      ' true to cancel the 'editing' mode of a cell:
      Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than storing the selected cell references on a separate or hidden sheet, the highlighted cell references could be stored in-memory. They just need to be initialized upon loading the sheet (via a `Worksheet_Activate()` method), but will otherwise work in a similar way.

Add the following code to the relevant Sheet within the Workbook:

```
' Set of highlighted cells indexed by row number
Dim highlightedCells As New Collection

' Scan existing sheet for any cells coloured 'red' and initialise the
'  run-time collection of 'highlighted' cells.
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim existingHighlights As Range
    ' Reset the collection of highlighted cells ready to rebuild it
    Set highlightedCells = New Collection
    ' Find the first cell that has its background coloured red
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Set existingHighlights = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("", _
                                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                                    SearchFormat:=True)
    ' Process for as long as we have more matches
    Do While Not existingHighlights Is Nothing
        cRow = existingHighlights.Row
        ' Add a reference only to the first coloured cell if multiple
        ' exist in a single row (will only occur if background manually set)
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
            Call highlightedCells.Add(existingHighlights.Address, CStr(cRow))
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Search from the cell after the last match. Note an error in Excel
        '  appears to prevent the FindNext method from finding formats correctly
        Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Set existingHighlights = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("", _
                                                    After:=existingHighlights, _
                                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                                    SearchFormat:=True)
        ' Abort the search if we've looped back to the top of the sheet
        If (existingHighlights.Row < cRow) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim hCell As String
    Dim cellAlreadyHighlighted As Boolean
    hCell = ""

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
      hCell = highlightedCells.Item(CStr(Target.Row))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (hCell <> "") Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(hCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        If (hCell = Target.Address) Then
            Call highlightedCells.Remove(CStr(Target.Row))
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else
            Call highlightedCells.Remove(CStr(Target.Row))
            Call highlightedCells.Add(Target.Address, CStr(Target.Row))
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Else
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
          highlightedCells.Remove (CStr(Target.Row))
        On Error GoTo 0
        Call highlightedCells.Add(Target.Address, CStr(Target.Row))
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to hear it @Mohammad Mbydeen. Perhaps you could up-vote it as a thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to reset the cell color to a normal cell, not specifically fill it with a white background.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    Dim iCOLOR As Long
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex <> 3 Then _
        iCOLOR = 3
    Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    If iCOLOR = 3 Then _
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = iCOLOR

End Sub
```

The method for removing a fill is to set the `.Interior.Pattern = xlNone`.

If a solid white cell fill is desired when not red then it can be switched on and off with this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    Dim iCOLOR As Long
    iCOLOR = 3 + CBool(Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3)
    Rows(Target.Row).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = iCOLOR

End Sub
```

Of course, a [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247%28v=office.11%29.aspx) presents a different set of problems.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Dim iCOLOR As Long
        iCOLOR = 3 + CBool(Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3)
        Intersect(Rows(Target.Row), ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = iCOLOR
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but your code changed the table background and the background of the entire row in the worksheet, I don't want to change the background for the entire row. when the user click to highlight the cell, it just highlighted to red and de-highlighted to white. please could you help ??

Comment: It is unclear on how wide you want to set the cell fill to white but if that is preferred then I've adjusted the code above to backfill the entire row white in order that two cells cannot be red at the same time in the same row.

Comment: Here is the problem, I have a table with white background and the user is able to add rows and columns to the table by clicking a buttons that assigned to macros, I want the user just be able to highlight the cell inside the table because the background of the table is white and the background of the whole sheet is grey, using your code it changes the background for the whole row.the table is from A:G and can be extended

Comment: The fact that you were dealing with a listobject table would have been good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` method to keep track of the 'highlighted' cell by placing the double clicked cell's reference on a hidden sheet, then either use conditional formatting or explicit checks in your event handler to highlight the relevant cell (or "cells" if you are allowing a single cell on multiple rows to be selected) based on the value(s) on the hidden sheet. If you choose to use conditional formatting, whenever a new cell is 'double clicked', the reference is updated on the hidden sheet and conditional formatting is automatically recalculated. Only one cell on a given row will ever remain 'highlighted'.

Alternatively, you could do it explicitly by adjusting your double click event handling code along the lines of the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If (Not (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value))) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = Target.Address
    ActiveSheet.Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

This way you could also check for any highlighted cell(s) upon loading the sheet and reset them if appropriate (assuming the user is permitted to save changes).

To highlight just one cell on any given row (but allowing multiple rows to have a single highlighted cell), you could use the following (this also toggles the highlight in an already highlighted cell):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If (Not (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value))) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        If (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Target.Address) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = ""
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Target.Address
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Target.Address
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Its working, but it place the reference of the highlighted cell in the first cell of the row, and I don't want that, please do you have another solution ?

Comment: @Mohammad Mbydeen - I've posted an alternative that stores the highlighted cells in memory as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    'Target must be between column "A" which is 1 & "G" which is 7 and also between row 1 and 10.
    'I also add checking for row. If you don't need, remove it.
    If Target.Column >= 1 And Target.Column <= 7 And Target.row >= 1 And Target.row <= 10 Then

      If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            ' if cell is already red, remove the color:
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
      Else
            ' make the cell red:
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End If

      ' true to cancel the 'editing' mode of a cell:
      Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you !! but this code just for one column, I wanted to range of rows, could you please help ?

Comment: Not clear your requirement. Say more with some examples. I will try it.

Comment: Here is the problem, I have a table with white background and the user is able to add rows and columns to the table by clicking a buttons that assigned to macros, I want the user just be able to highlight the cell inside the table because the background of the table is white and the background of the whole sheet is grey, using your code it changes the background for the whole row.the table is from A:G and can be extended

Comment: Ok, I got you. I modify my answer for you. Try it. If it is work, accept the answer,. Thanks.!